# putStringArray() using String 2-Dimensional array (String[][] )

Tags: android, arrays, bundle

I want to pass a 2-D String Array to another activity.
My S2-D String Array  (String[][]) is 'selected_list'.

code is :

```
     Bundle list_bundle=new Bundle();
     list_bundle.putStringArray("lists",selected_list); 
     Intent list_Intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), view_selected_items.class);
     startActivityForResult(list_Intent, 2);
```

But putStringArray("lists",selected_list) is showing a error like we can pass only 1-Dimensional Array (String[]).

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`putSerializable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putSerializable%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable%29).  Arrays are serializable, provided their elements are.

To store:

```
list_bundle.putSerializable("lists", selected_list);
```

To access:

```
String[][] selected_list = (String[][]) bundle.getSerializable("lists");
```

Comment: Please tell me if we use putSerializable(), then how to retrieve the String values using getSerializable()?

Comment: Hi Matthew, 
When I am using that code, my process is suddently stopped. I am new in Android. Please help me. I don't know how to solve this problem.
In my second activity, I need to take the String array values and display it to a TextView named 'items'. My code is:        
        Bundle item_bundle=this.getIntent().getExtras();
        String [][] selected_list = (String[][]) item_bundle.getSerializable("lists");   
        TextView items=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_items);
        selected_item=selected_list[0][0]+selected_list[0][1];
        items.setText(selected_item);

Answer (score 1):

This finally works well for me : Thanks to Matthew and Mehdiway

To start a new activity (sending String[][] and String):

```
String[][] arrayToSend=new String[3][30];
String stringToSend="Hello";
Intent i = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);

i.putExtra("key_string",stringToSend);

Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
mBundle.putSerializable("key_array_array",  arrayToSend);
i.putExtras(mBundle);

startActivity(i);
```

To access in NewActivity.onCreate:

```
String sReceived=getIntent().getExtras().getString("key_string");

String[][] arrayReceived=null;
Object[] objectArray = (Object[]) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("key_array_array");
if(objectArray!=null){
    arrayReceived = new String[objectArray.length][];
    for(int i=0;i<objectArray.length;i++){
        arrayReceived[i]=(String[]) objectArray[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Matthew said, you can put the string array in the bundle like this

```
Bundle list_bundle=new Bundle();
list_bundle.putStringArray("lists",selected_list);
```

This works very well, but when you try to get the array via `(String[][]) bundle.getSerializable("lists");` it gives a

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.util.String
```

So what you have to do is this :

```
    Object[] objectArray = (Object[]) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("lists");
    int horizontalLength = 0;
    if (objectArray.length > 0)
        horizontalLength = ((Object[]) objectArray[0]).length; // See explanation to understand the cast
    String[][] my_list = new String[objectArray.length][horizontalLength];
    int i = 0;
    for(Object row : objectArray)
    {
        my_list[i][0] = ((String[])row)[0];
        my_list[i++][1] = ((String[])row)[1];
    }
```

#### **Explanation :**

When you get the array as I Serializable object it doesn't behave the same way a simple String array does, instead it considers every row as a *separate* array, so what you have to do is to read the Serializable object as a one dimensional array, and then cast every row of it to a String[] array. Et voila !