# how to pass array value to next activity

Tags: android

i want to pass all the array values to next activity .but i dont know how to do that 
how to use arrayList to implement this .

i have done this coding but it give me an error when i click on the button
i closed applicaton forcefully

```
package com.example.snooder;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout; 
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;

public class players extends Activity {





LinearLayout player_layout;
Bundle b;

List<EditText> allEds = new ArrayList<EditText>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.players);

    b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String resStr = b.getString("name");

    player_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.player_layout);

    EditText[] ed1 = new EditText[Integer.parseInt(resStr)+1];
    Button add_player = new Button(players.this);
    add_player.setText("Add Players");


    for(int i=1;i<=Integer.parseInt(resStr);i++)
    {
        ed1[i] = new EditText(players.this);
        allEds.add(ed1[i]);
        player_layout.addView(ed1[i]);
        ed1[i].setId(i);
        ed1[i].setHint("enter player" +i+ "name");
        ed1[i].setHeight(50);
        ed1[i].setWidth(300);


            add_player.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                    Intent intent = new        Intent(players.this,player_name.class);
                    String[] strings = new     String[allEds.size()];


                    for(int i=0; i < allEds.size(); i++){
                        strings[i] = allEds.get(i).getText().toString();
                    }
                    for(int i=0;i<allEds.size();i++)
                      {
                         intent.putExtra("playerName",strings[i].toString());
                      }
                      startActivity(intent);

                }
            });

    }

    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    player_layout.addView(add_player, lp);












}
```

}

Comment: I'm looking at your code now, but you should post the error message you get. Preferably, post your logcat. Also, it is hard to tell exactly what you are doing.  You should try explaining exactly what is going on here.

Comment: As per you code. once you click on a player the new activity should open? So do you want to send the player name or the list of all the players also??

Comment: i just want players name in TextView in next activity. if i have two edittext then two Textview should be displayed with edittext values

Comment: onClick(player.java 72) in logcat

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing string array between android activities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429036/passing-string-array-between-android-activities)

Answer (score 0):

The error happens here:

> intent.putExtra("playerName",strings[i].toString());

At this point, the array `strings` is still empty; you are trying to reference null values.

With regards to your question, however, you got the proper method: put the values in the intent that will be sent to the next activity. You can use `putExtra` that takes a String array as shown on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217153/passing-string-array-between-two-class-in-android-application).

Answer (score 0):

You are adding all extras with same name in the end it is going to be just one.

There is overloaded version of [putExtra for array of strings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)