# Android share intent for multiple jokes

Tags: android, android-intent

I am creating an android app for jokes. I have multiple jokes which i want to share with whatsapp users.

Do i need write share intent individually for each jokes?

For Example:

```
public void share(View view) 
    {
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
           sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
           sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
               "Q: What did the butcher say when he backed into the meat-grinder?
A: Looks like I'm getting a little behind in my work!");
           sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
           startActivity(sendIntent);
    }
```

please help.

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217153/passing-string-array-between-two-class-in-android-application> might be help you...

Comment: hi..I am at the beginner level for Android Development. will u please give an example because i dint understand anything from that link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948373/android-share-plain-text-using-intent-to-all-messaging-apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it easier to understand, just think that Intent is a courier, that help you delivery data from Activity1 to Activity2.

In this case, you can try a simple way: put your joke inside a string:

`String joke = "Q: What did the butcher say when he backed into the meat-grinder?\n
A: Looks like I'm getting a little behind in my work!";`

`sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,joke);`

Enjoy trying other way, when you improve your Java

Comment: Thank u very much Jacky. now the concept is clear. but do i have to write intents individually for each jokes?

Comment: no, instead, you can start trying by writing each joke with each string. Example: String joke1 = ....; String joke2 = .... ; and "putExtra" those variable to intent. joke1, joke2 ... is the 'packet', inside the 'truck' Intent, that being delivered.

Comment: As u know I'm new to android development.. Will u please give me an example with complete code. Thanks once again for all your help. Highly appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at this sample: http://www.codeshare.io/lFtuQ If you are willing to see real code, and i'm assume that you know how to rebuild from other's code, i will send you entire code

Comment: hi jacky...i'm using in fragment... plz have a look at this code http://www.codeshare.io/D3DiH ...it's giving me the error for getInent() & i changed to this also Intent sendIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), JokeActivity.class); because it was giving me the error. and please also tell me how my xml file will look like main.xml & jokes.xml. sorry for bothering you. Thanks once again.

Comment: It seems that it's hard to explain in just few words :), just give me your codes (may be zip file) and tell me what do you want, i will try modify it. Hope can give you one good example