# how to send multiple data to another app

Tags: android

I would like to send data to another specific app. The following will send a String to the specified app.

How can i send 3 Strings to the app?
Do i have to put them in an Array or use a HashMap?

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setClassName("com.example.application",
            "com.example.application.MainActivity");
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "String1");
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use more putExtra's just use other names!

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setClassName("com.example.application",
        "com.example.application.MainActivity");
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra("First", "String1");
sendIntent.putExtra("Second", "String2");
sendIntent.putExtra("Third", "String3");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

And get the strings:

```
String first = null;
String second = null;
String third = null;

if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null) {
        first = extras.getString("First");
        second= extras.getString("Second");
        third = extras.getString("Third");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In sender app

```
String[] myStrings = new String[] {"string1", "string2","string3"};
intent.putExtra("strings", myStrings);
```

In receiver app

```
String[] myStrings = intent.getStringArrayExtra("strings");
```

Got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217153/passing-string-array-between-two-class-in-android-application).

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setClassName("com.example.application",
            "com.example.application.MainActivity");
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra("StringOne", "StringValue1");
    sendIntent.putExtra("StringThree", "StringValue3");
    sendIntent.putExtra("StringTwo", "StringValue3");
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    startActivity(sendIntent);
```

in the received activity

```
getIntent().getStringExtra(StringOne);
getIntent().getStringExtra(StringThree);
getIntent().getStringExtra(StringTwo);
```