# How do I pass a string array to an activity

Tags: android, eclipse

I wrote this code on my first page:

```
Intent i = new Intent(quiz1.this, answer1.class);
i.putExtra("answer", answer);
startActivity(i);
```

And this on my second page:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String[] answer = extras.getStringArray("answer");
```

But it gives me the following error:

> "unfortunately, myapp has stopped"

Comment: Also show crash logs with question and at which line getting crash

Comment: I don't have android emulator in eclipse I'm using bluestack

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing String array between two class in android application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217153/passing-string-array-between-two-class-in-android-application)

Comment: I try it before it didn't work

Comment: what should i do????????????

Comment: @Mani See my answer below :)

Comment: Mani, is working my answer?

Answer (score -1):

Use this in your second Activity

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
String [] answer = intent.getStringArrayExtra("answer");
```

Comment: Just to note, while this is different syntax, it's still exactly the same as the OP's code.  It makes no difference if you use the Bundle or the Intent, both should work.

Comment: unfortunately, myapp has stopped

Comment: @Mani  May be this is not what is causing the problem

Answer (score -1):

If you are passing `answer` as a value assuming it is declared as `String[]` you could create a `Bundle` as follows :

```
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putStringArray("answer", answer);
Intent i = new Intent(quiz1.this, answer1.class);
i.putExtras(b);
startActivity(i);
```

Then in your second activity you get the data doing this :

```
Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
String[] answer =b.getStringArray("answer");
```